# Get a box with zero depth including some text

Tags: boxes

How to get a box including some text in text mode, which depth 0pt?

Comment: Can you give a more precise question to adapt my answer? What you want to do exactly with your text ?

Comment: @Altermundus I want the M.S.'s answer! Thanks you too!

Comment: @M.S. No problem!

Comment: "at" replies are only seen by the addressee if you use the first few characters of the username.  So "@Martin" or "@MartinScharrer" will get noticed but not "@M.S."

Comment: @ Matthew, I got it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to modify the official height and depth of some text:

```
\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{<text>}
```

This raises the text by 0pt (so not at all), keeps the official height identical to the original height and sets the depth to 0pt.

Comment: @M.S.That is exactly what I want! Thank you.

Comment: Just a note to clarify that the first optional parameter specifies the height (that is, x-height), and the second the depth (distance to lowest descender). And `\height` is a command to get the natural height of `<text>`.

Answer (score 13):

`\smash{great}` is a box with zero height and no depth

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\SBox
\begin{document}
\sbox\SBox{great}%
\the\wd\SBox\\
\the\ht\SBox\\
\the\dp\SBox

\sbox\SBox{\smash{great}}%
\the\wd\SBox\\
\the\ht\SBox\\
\the\dp\SBox

\sbox\SBox{\smash[b]{great}}%% Needs amsmath
\the\wd\SBox\\
\the\ht\SBox\\
\the\dp\SBox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert But if I use `\smash{a}` in text mode, the letter `a` turned a math italic shape.

Comment: no, that is not possible, only inside math you'll get an italic a.

Comment: @Herbert: With amsmath you can also say `\smash[b]{g}` to get zero depth and unmodified height (there's also `\smash[t]{...}`.

Comment: @Herbert Ehh, I just put the `\smash` in `\DeclareMathOperator`, that is, `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Sup}{su\smash{p}}` and use `$\Sup$`. While `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Sup}{su\raisebox[0pt]{\height][0pt]{p}}` is good.

Comment: @egred: I know ... there is also a [bt]. But this is not the problem here ...

Comment: @Stufazi Hoqckt: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Sup}{su\smash{p}}` this is set in math mode and the one with `\raisebox` is set in text mode! With `\textrm{\smash{p}}` you also have it in text mode.

Comment: @Herbert Another solution! This is useful to me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but if you want  a special box with special dim then you can try :

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{}
\ht\mybox=10mm \dp\mybox=0pt \wd\mybox=20mm
```

But If you put some text in your initial `\hbox`, you can have some strange results !
When you make a box with some contents, height, depth and width depend of the context.

Comment: You should not modifiy the height and width, unless you are looking for "strange results"!!!

Comment: Thanks, I just want a box, inside it is some text, and the box is no depth.