# How to set the baseline for headers with scrpage2?

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, koma-script, scrpage2

I want the left and the right header to have the same baseline, regardless of the height of the content they yield. To demonstrate this, assume

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\ohead{\Huge\thesection -- \Large\leftmark}
\ihead{\small Report No. 11}
\ofoot{\small Page \thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

The output will be equivalent to

[image: The header baselines don't match]

I added red line to emphasize the difference in the baseline.

**Question:** How can I set them both to the same baseline?

**Considered solutions:**

- Add to the smaller header something like `\vphantom{\Huge A}` to implicitly make it the same height.
- Use `fancyhdr` as it aligns the baselines (Well, it brings other issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell LaTeX that you *want* `\Large` also in the inner heading by setting a strut and adding some to the `\headheight`. This will ensure that the elements of the heading will fit in the reserved area.

I can't recommend using three different font sizes in the heading; actually I advise to reconsider the choice of the big number; I removed the dash that's really horrible.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\ohead{\smash{\Huge\thesection}\ \ \Large\leftmark}
\ihead{\small Report No. 11\Large\strut}
\ofoot{\small Page \thepage}
\addtolength{\headheight}{4pt} % Better keeping the number in the reserved box
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\begin{document}

\section{Start of report}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THe command `\smash` ignores descenders. Does it? ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes; but they will fall too deep in the right part (the section title).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick solution: use a box of zero height to achieve the alignment:

```
\documentclass[headlines=1.5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\ohead{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Huge\thesection -- \Large\leftmark}}
\ihead{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\small Report No. 11}}
\ofoot{\small Page \thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{First section p}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] ([yshift=-60pt]current page.north west) -- +(\paperwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used TikZ just to draw a visual guideline.

Comment: There’s a sneaky issue: According to KOMA-Script documentation the default is `headlines=1.25`, so you actually made the head tighter.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command `\smash`. The trick is explained here: [Get a box with zero depth including some text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/get-a-box-with-zero-depth-including-some-text/16543#16543)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\makeatletter

\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\ohead{\smash{\Huge\thesection -- \Large\leftmark}}
\ihead{\smash{\small Report No. 11}}
\ofoot{\small Page \thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

[image]