# Ignoring actual height and width of box

Tags: boxes

I would like the following TikZ qtree to come out symmetric:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree[.O [.N O R ] [.O N \fbox R ] [.R N O ]]
\end{document}
```

(so that, in particular, the edge from the root to its child 'O' is vertical).  Since

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree[.O [.N O R ] [.O N R ] [.R N O ]]
\end{document}
```

*is* symmetric, obviously it's the `\fbox` that's preventing this; so I thought that something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree[.O [.N O R ] [.O N {\smash{\fbox R}\phantom R} ] [.R N O ]]
\end{document}
```

would work, but it seems actually to be *worse*.  (I think that this doesn't really have anything to do with qtree, which is why I didn't put it in the tags, but I couldn't think up an equivalent example without it.)

(EDIT:  Per @DavidCarlisle's advice, I made all code snippets compile-able.)

Comment: please always post complete documents not fragments that can't be run without effort, but `\smash` only hides the  height not the width so `\smash{\fbox R}\phantom R` is more than twice as wide as  `R` you may prefer `\frame{R}` to `\fbox{R}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the advice.  (a) The three code samples are now complete documents.  (b) Oops, my mistake; but *is* there a command that hides height *and* width?  (c) Why would I prefer `\frame`?

Comment: Gonzalo's given an answer but I for example didn't recognise the package so I wouldn't have been able to test the example, although I could otherwise answer the hiding width question. I just offered \frame as an alternative as it is not so often seen but it is a variant of fbox that _doesn't_ add the extra width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks.  I'm looking for something with the same visual appearance as `\fbox R` (which `\frame R` doesn't seem to be), but that is perceived by `TeX` as having the height and width of an undecorated `R`.  I did see Gonzalo's answer, which accomplishes the effect that I want; but is there any general command that forces a box to be treated as having 0 height and width?

Comment: `\makebox(0,0){foo}` (the round bracket form is mainly used in picture environment but works generally and allows specification of height and depth, to 0 here)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks once again.  Having tried replacing `\smash{\fbox R}` by `\makebox(0,0){\fbox R}` in my example, I see that I should prefer Gonzalo's example because it handles the spacing correctly.

Comment: yes, beware what you ask for:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trick TeX to see only a box of the width of the boxed character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\Tree[.O [.N O R ] [.O N \makebox[\widthof{R}][c]{\fbox{R}} ] [.R N O ]]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  *Is* there, more generally, any way to convince `TeX` that a box has zero height and <strike>depth</strike> width?   (I was simply blindly believing [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16543/1169), which either I misunderstood or is incorrect.)  (EDIT:  I now see that I have been using `depth' when I meant `width'.)

Comment: @LSpice You're welcome. Notice that the box won't have zero width; it will have a width equal to the width of "R".

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that it thus bypasses the need for the extra `\phantom R`.  I was wondering (in my comments to David Carlisle in the original question) if I could avoid the dependence on `calc`, but, as I think about it more, why bother?

Comment: @LSpice Have a look at `\rlap`, `\clap`, `\llap`, `\mathrlap`, `\mathclap` and `\mathllap` from `\usepackage{mathtools}`.