# How to keep base-line based distance before (tikz) environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, line-spacing, baseline

I have an environment (`tikzpicture`) that tries to occupy a height equal to the multiple of the current line height / baselineskip (I need this to be pixel-perfect, so in a multicol-setup the baselines match up in all columns before/after the image).

The fixed tikz height itself seems to work, but the environment itself does not keep a correct baseline-based spacing to the preceding paragraph. If letters extend below the baseline (e.g. a 'g'), the gap to the previous baseline is different than without extending characters.

[image: different spacing before environment]

How can I make sure the environment keeps an automatic baseline-based distance to the previous paragraph? I have many many uses of this environment in my document, so I do not want to manually add fixes based on the preceding content.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Test g.

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}

Test

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: My best solution so far is to output a `\phantom{g}` paragraph before the environment and then use a `\vspace{-1\baselineskip}` to position over it. Feels a bit like a hack though.

Answer (score 3):

This is not related with tikz, but with how TeX make paragraphs. Latex use the rubber length `\baselineskip` to set the distance between lines (plus `\parskip` if it is the beginning of a paragraph). But if you add a tikzpicture, or other box that make the line higher, then, *if the lines would be too close together, closer than \lineskiplimit, then TeX instead uses \lineskip as the interline glue* (see [here](https://latexref.xyz/_005cbaselineskip-_0026-_005cbaselinestretch.html)), and this interline glue takes into account the *depth* of the previous line.

An example:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-0.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}
%\setlength{\lineskip}{0cm}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline={(#1.base)}] 
\node[inner sep=0pt, line width=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{Tg}};}

\begin{document}

\fbox{Test}\fbox{g} \tikzmark{A}

\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}} \tikzmark{B}

\fbox{Test} \tikzmark{C}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\fbox{Test} \tikzmark{D}

\fbox{Test}\fbox{g} \tikzmark{D2}

\fbox{Test} \tikzmark{D3}

\fbox{Test}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, font=\tiny]
    \draw[red] (A.south) -- node[right] {lineskip} ++(down:\lineskip);
    \draw[red, transform canvas={xshift=-0.43cm}] (B.base) -- node[right] {baselineskip} ++(down:\baselineskip);
    \draw[red] (C.base) -- node[right] {lineskip} ++(down:\lineskip);
    \draw[red] (D.base) -- node[right] {baselineskip} ++(down:\baselineskip);
    \draw[red] (D2.base) -- node[right] {baselineskip} ++(down:\baselineskip);
    \draw[red] (D3.base) -- node[right] {baselineskip} ++(down:\baselineskip);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can try remove the depth from the previous line ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16539/96422)):

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-0.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}
%\setlength{\lineskip}{0cm}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline={(#1.base)}] 
\node[inner sep=0pt, line width=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{Tg}};}
\newcommand{\zerodepth}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\fbox{Test}\fbox{\zerodepth{g}}

\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\fbox{Test} 

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip]
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but this solution is not going to work with whole paragraphs.

EDIT: Another option is add a `\strut` at the end of the line of paragraph avobe the tikz picture.

Comment: In my real document I use `\setlength{\thelineheight}{13pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}` to avoid the glue, but maybe that's not enough.

Comment: Great analysis.  Just noting that `\tikzmark` is now provided by the `tikzmark` library (what you use here is closest to `\tikzmarknode` from that package).

Comment: @TeXter I do not know `\thelineheight` length. I think that what you need is fix the glue between paragraphs to zero: `\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}` (removing the "rubber")